# What is the difference between blue and purple bytes stored in Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

From Hosting menu in Firebase Console I just wonder what is the difference between blue and purple bytes stored?

[image: Firebase Console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. This is actually a glitch in the Firebase Hosting reporting system. As you can see, the line is continuous from blue to purple, it's simply being represented as two different data sets.